# Making UDP broadcast work with wifi router

Tags: udp, broadcast, packet, netcat

I'd like to test out UDP broadcast on a very simple network: an old wifi router (WRT54GS) that's not connected to the internet at all, an android tablet, and my macbook:

```
[Tablet] <\/\/\/\/\/> [Wifi Router] <\/\/\/\/\/> [Macbook]
```

where the wavy lines indicate wireless connections.

The Macbook has IP address 192.168.1.101, the tablet has IP address 192.168.1.102. The router is 192.168.1.1.

To avoid too much low-level detail, I wanted to use netcat to do my testing. I decided to use port 11011 because it was easy to type.

As a first step, I thought I'd try just making this work from the macbook back to itself. In two terminal windows, I ran these programs

> Window 1: `% nc  -ul 11011`

which I started up first, and then:

> Window 2: `% echo 'foo' |  nc -v -u  255.255.255.255  11011`

Nothing showed up in Window 1. The result in Window 2 was this:

```
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
    outif (null)
    src 192.168.1.2 port 61985
    dst 255.255.255.255 port 11011
    rank info not available
```

I'm fairly certain I'm missing something obvious here. Can someone familiar with nc spot my obvious error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a multi-part answer, gleaned from other SO and SuperUser answers and a bit of guesswork.

**Mac-to-mac communication via UDP broadcast over wifi**

The first thing is that the mac version of netcat (nc) as of Oct 2018 doesn't support broadcast, so you have to switch to "socat", which is far more general and powerful in what it can send. As for the listening side, what worked for me, eventually, was

```
Terminal 1: % nc  -l -u 11011
```

What about the sending side? Well, it turns out I needed more information. For instance, trying this with the localhost doesn't work at all, because that particular "interface" (gosh, I hate the overloading of words in CS; as a mathematician, I'd hope that CS people might have learned from our experience what a bad idea this is...) doesn't support broadcast. And how did I learn that? Via `ifconfig`, a tool that shows how your network is configured. In my case, the output was this:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
  options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
  inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
  inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
  inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
  nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
  gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
  stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
  ether 98:01:a7:8a:6b:35 
  inet 192.168.1.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
  media: autoselect
  status: active
en1: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
  options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
  ether 4a:00:05:f3:ac:30 
  media: autoselect <full-duplex>
  status: inactive
en2: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
  options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
  ether 4a:00:05:f3:ac:31 
  media: autoselect <full-duplex>
  status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
  options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
  ether 4a:00:05:f3:ac:30 
  Configuration:
    id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
    maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
    root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
    ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
  member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
        ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
  member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
        ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
  media: <unknown type>
  status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
  ether 0a:01:a7:8a:6b:35 
  media: autoselect
  status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
  ether 7e:00:76:6d:5c:09 
  inet6 fe80::7c00:76ff:fe6d:5c09%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
  nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
media: autoselect
status: active
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
inet6 fe80::773a:6d9e:1d47:7502%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa 
nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

most of which means nothing to me. But look at "en0", the ethernet connection to the wireless network (192.168). The data there really tells you something. The `flags` tell you that it supports broadcast and multicast. Two lines late, the word `broadcast` appears again, followed by `192.168.1.255`, which suggested to me that this might be the right address to which to send broadcast packets.

With that in mind, I tried this:

```
Terminal 2: % echo -n "TEST" | socat - udp-datagram:192.168.1.255:11011,broadcast
```

with the result that in Terminal 1, the word `TEST` appeared!

When I retyped the same command in Terminal 2, nothing more appeared in Terminal 1; it seems that the "listen" is listening for a single message, for reasons I do not understand. But hey, at least it's getting me somewhere!

**Mac to tablet communication**

First, on the tablet, I tried to mimic the listening side of the mac version above. The termux version of `nc` didn't support the `-u` flag, so I had to do something else. I decided to use socat. As a first step, I got it working mac-to-mac (via the wifi router of course). It turns out that to listen for UDP packets, you have to use `udp-listen` rather than `udp-datagram`, but otherwise it was pretty simple. In the end, it looked like this:

```
Terminal 1: % socat udp-listen:11011 -
```

meaning "listen for stuff on port 11011 and copy to standard output", and

```
Terminal 2: % echo -n "TEST" | socat - udp-datagram:192.168.1.255:11011,broadcast
```

Together, this got data from Terminal 2 to Terminal 1.

Then I tried it on the tablet. As I mentioned, `nc` on the tablet was feeble. But `socat` was missing entirely.

I tried it, found it wasn't installed, and installed it.

Once I'd done that, on the Tablet I typed

```
Tablet: % socat udp-listen:11011 -
```

and on the mac, in Terminal 2, I once again typed

```
Terminal 2: echo -n "TEST" | socat - udp-datagram:192.168.1.255:11011,broadcast
```

and sure enough, the word `TEST` appeared on the tablet!

Even better, by reading the docs I found I could use

```
socat udp:recv:11011 -
```

which not only listens, but continues to listen, and hence will report multiple UDP packets, one after another. (`udp-listen`, by contrast, seems to wait for one packet and then try to communicate back with the sender of that packet, which isn't what I wanted at all.)